# Is it possible to refer icons from jars on JavaFX CSS stylesheet using -fx-graphic?

Tags: java, css, maven, javafx, stylesheet

I'm using Tango Icon Theme in my project as a maven dependency.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.freedesktop.tango</groupId>
   <artifactId>tango-icon-theme</artifactId>
   <version>0.8.90</version>
</dependency>
```

**Stylesheet :**

```
.button-dropcontent {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-graphic: url('<??JAR??>/org.freedesktop.tango/22x22/emblems/emblem-unreadable.png');
}
```

Is it possible to refer icons of this dependency?

Does anybody has an example for this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can. If you want to load a file from a jar file, you need to make sure of the following :

- The jar is on the classpath
- You are using the complete url of the image file ***without quotation marks***.

Something like this should work :

```
.button {
    -fx-graphic: url(/org/freedesktop/tango/22x22/emblems/emblem-unreadable.png);
}
```

For more information read the [URI section of JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typeurl).

This is the output that I get, using the same tango image file, on a button.

[image]